# Android webview after onJsAlert not responding taps

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have override my WebChromeClient's onJsAlert behavior like:

```
WebChromeClient wvcc = new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
    //...
    return true;
    }
}
```

my application successfully handle the Js alerts and suppressed the original alert. However, after the alert event, I can no longer click my buttons(in list-items of listview) on the web page in my webview. 
I am currently using jquery mobile to build my web.

Is there anything else I should aware of?

Comment: Just faced the same proble, see solution below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just faced the exactly same problem. I wanted to generate a custom android dialog instead of the alert, to this is the final solution:

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, final String url, String message,
            JsResult result) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        arg0.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
        result.cancel();
        return true;
    }
});
```

The key is the `result.cancel();` and `return true;`, I tested in several combinations, and the only one that did not fired the default JS alert AND didn't caused the touch problem was this combination

Comment: Calling the result.comfirm() also works. And I think you should call the result.confirm() in the onClick method block. And of course you should make method parameter result as final.

Comment: Thank you so much bro.. result.cancel(); Worked for me.

Comment: result.cancel(); saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you should call result.confirm() method, my solution is :

```
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                final JsResult result) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "onJsAlert url=" + url + ";message=" + message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            result.confirm();
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the similar problem (but with `onJsPrompt` in my case) and the suggested solution did not work for me. I have already had the calls to `result.cancel()/result.confirm()` and `return true` from the handler. The key for the fix was found in the source code of [`JsDialogHelper`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/7de7e0b0dd61acba813dec3a07d29f1d62026470/core/java/android/webkit/JsDialogHelper.java).

This was the line which I spotted to solve my issue:

```
builder.setOnCancelListener(new CancelListener());
```

The complete handler code:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, final JsPromptResult result)
  {
    final EditText data = new EditText(view.getContext());
    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
    .setTitle(view.getTitle())
    .setView(data)
    .setMessage(message)
    .setOnCancelListener(new CancelListener(result)) // if this line is missing, WebView remains unresponsive after the dialog is shown and closed once
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
        result.confirm(data.getText().toString());
      }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
      {
        result.cancel();
      }
    });

    b.show();

    return true;
  }
```

where `CancelListener` can be defined as a simple stub class:

```
private class CancelListener implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener,
DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
  CancelListener(JsResult result)
  {
    mResult = result;
  }

  private final JsResult mResult;

  @Override
  public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
  {
    mResult.cancel();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
  {
    mResult.cancel();
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug in WebView, or is it **required** to always have a cancel listener defined to keep webview's dialogs working properly.